# Minimum requirements to run Sql Server BCP.exe utility

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am working with a client who needs to do a data import to a remote SQL Server (2008) instance. The machine that the import will be done from cannot have SQL Server installed on it. Can the BCP.exe utility run without a SQL Server install?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use one of the [SQL Server distributable packages](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978) to stay within licensing terms. These are not full installs.

The one you want is "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Command Line Utilities"

Note: copying bcp.exe by itself will not work

Answer (score 1):

Copy `bcp.rll` from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\Resources\1033`.

Put `bcp.exe` & `bcp.rll` in the same folder.

That should allow BCP to run.